# php json example not working

Tags: php, json

Reading "PHP & jQuery Cookbook" right now and it gives this example for using json_decode()

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
{
  "origin":"Delhi",
  "destination":"London",
  "passengers":
  [
    {
      "name":"Mr. Perry Mason",
      "type":"Adult",
      "age":28
    }
    {
      "name":"Miss Irene Adler",
      "type":"Adult",
      "age":25
    }
  ],
  "travelDate":"17-Dec-2010"
}
JSON;

$objJson = json_decode($json);
echo ($objJson);

?>
```

The code just gives me a blank page when I run it. Is there something invalid about that JSON? Because json_decode() doesnt even seem to see it.

Comment: Your json is invalid. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i honestly don't know what that means, pretty new to coding and this site so..

Comment: nvm i just looked it up, i always accept correct answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather use print_r() than using echo to see if it prints

but a comma is missing from your JSON input

it should be like this

```
 {
  "name":"Mr. Perry Mason",
  "type":"Adult",
  "age":28
},
{
  "name":"Miss Irene Adler",
  "type":"Adult",
  "age":25
}
```

Comment: I am glad I could be of any help

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON  is invalid:

```
Parse error on line 9:
... "age": 28        }{            "name"
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

Your missing a comma in your passengers array.

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
{
  "origin":"Delhi",
  "destination":"London",
  "passengers":
  [
    {
      "name":"Mr. Perry Mason",
      "type":"Adult",
      "age":28
    },
{
  "name":"Miss Irene Adler",
  "type":"Adult",
  "age":25
}
  ],
  "travelDate":"17-Dec-2010"
}
JSON;

$objJson = json_decode($json);
echo ($objJson);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you'r missing a comma after the closing bracket after "age":28} so your JSON should be:

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
{
  "origin":"Delhi",
  "destination":"London",
  "passengers":
  [
    {
      "name":"Mr. Perry Mason",
      "type":"Adult",
      "age":28
    },
    {
      "name":"Miss Irene Adler",
      "type":"Adult",
      "age":25
    }
  ],
  "travelDate":"17-Dec-2010"
}
JSON;

$objJson = json_decode($json);
echo ($objJson);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
{
  "origin":"Delhi",
  "destination":"London",
  "passengers":
  [
    {
      "name":"Mr. Perry Mason",
      "type":"Adult",
      "age":28
    }**,**
    {
      "name":"Miss Irene Adler",
      "type":"Adult",
      "age":25
    }
  ],
  "travelDate":"17-Dec-2010"
}
JSON;

$objJson = json_decode($json);
**print_r** ($objJson);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First your JSON string is invalid,  there is a comma missing between the two elements of "passengers".
Second, `echo ($objJson)` won't work, because `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`. You may use var_dump or print_r.